# Runtime complexity of finding power set of a list of integers

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, subset

I have the following algorithm to return the power set of a given list of integers (power set = all possible subsets).

```
class Solution:
    def subsets_recursive(self, nums):
        """
        O(2^n). Space O(1)
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]

        Given a set of distinct integers, nums, return all possible subsets (the power set).
        Note: The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets.

        Example:

        Input: nums = [1,2,3]
        Output:
        [
          [3],
          [1],
          [2],
          [1,2,3],
          [1,3],
          [2,3],
          [1,2],
          []
        ]

        """
        # [1,2,3], [ [],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3] ]
        res = []
        self.generateSet(nums, 0, res, [])
        return res

    def generateSet(self, nums, startingPos, res, subRes):
        res.append(subRes[:])
        for i in range(startingPos, len(nums)):
            subRes.append(nums[i])
            self.generateSet(nums, i + 1, res, subRes)
            subRes.pop()
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out what is the runtime complexit of this recursive backtracking algorithm. I happen to know that for n numbers, there are 2^n members in its power set. But that is not the same as saying this particular algorithm runs in O(2^n).

So, how can I show that this particular algorithm also runs in O(2^n)? Or does it?

Comment: Just constructing the powerset of N items as a list of lists takes **O(N * 2^N)** time and **O(N * 2^N)** space.  I'm not gonna check your algorithm, but it's hard to imagine one that would be worse than that.

Comment: @MattTimmermans if you use that simple representation, but I believe you can have lists sharing "tails" reducing both time and space to O(2^N). I don't see way to be better than that.

Comment: @HansOlsson Sure... in Lisp or similar, or using your own linked list implementation, but we're talking about standard lists in Python.

Comment: Your code runs in O(2^n). By increasing `startingPos` you add and print value to output subset prefix and when subset with specific prefix is build up you just `pop` this value and go for next one. This gives you 2^n complexity. One simple way  to check complexity would be print number of recursive calls for different input length.